# Unity3d Array index is out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void FillGrid()
{ 
    for(int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
        {
            InstantiateCandy(x, y);
        }

    }
}
void InstantiateCandy(int x,int y)
{
    GameObject randomCandy = _candies[Random.Range(0, _candies.Length)];

    GameObject newCandy =(GameObject)Instantiate(randomCandy, new Vector3(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
    newCandy.GetComponent<GridItem>().OnItemPositionChanged(x, y);


}
void GetCandies()
{
    _candies = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Prefabs");

    for(int i=0; i< _candies.Length-1;i++)
    {
        _candies[i].GetComponent<GridItem>().id = i;
    }

}


}
```

My problem at this line :

```
GameObject randomCandy = _candies[Random.Range(0, _candies.Length)];
```

I'm unable to fix it. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Don't know anything about unity, but array [0,1,2] for example lentgh is 3 but last index is 2 because array index is zero based. Could this be the cause? Use .length - 1.

Comment: Is `_candies.Length` 0 by any chance?

Comment: @Sami: The second argument to `Random.Range` is an *exclusive* upper bound - unless both arguments are the same. (Personally I'd throw an exception there, but...)

Answer (score 2):

`_candies` is initialized in `GetCandies()`, but this function is not invoked, in your code. I suspect that, when the incriminated line is executed, `_candies` is still empty.